# Decreasing horizontal space between cases environment and `\Rightarrow`

Tags: math-mode, spacing, cases

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\sum\vec{F}= 0 \Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
\frac{{\partial {\sigma _{xx}}}}{{\partial x}} + \frac{{\partial {\sigma _{yx}}}}{{\partial y}} + \frac{{\partial {\sigma _{zx}}}}{{\partial z}} + {F_x} = 0\\
\frac{{\partial {\sigma _{xy}}}}{{\partial x}} + \frac{{\partial {\sigma _{yy}}}}{{\partial y}} + \frac{{\partial {\sigma _{zy}}}}{{\partial z}} + {F_y} = 0\\
\frac{{\partial {\sigma _{xz}}}}{{\partial x}} + \frac{{\partial {\sigma _{yz}}}}{{\partial y}} + \frac{{\partial {\sigma _{zz}}}}{{\partial z}} + {F_z} = 0
\end{cases}\Rightarrow {\frac{{\partial {\sigma _{ji}}}}{{\partial {x_j}}} + {F_j} = 0}
\]

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

One sees the undesired space between the cases environment and the second `\Rightarrow`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing special: you didn't use the  2nd part of the `cases` environment, and it inserts a quad to separate these parts. The simplest is to insert, just after `\end{cases}`, `\hspace{-1em}`.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you very much. Do you mean the `&` (when you say the 2nd part of the `cases`)?

Comment: @Bernard If this is the case (inserting `&` as, e.g., in `\frac{{\partial {\sigma _{xx}}}}{{\partial x}} + \frac{{\partial {\sigma _{yx}}}}{{\partial y}} + \frac{{\partial {\sigma _{zx}}}}{{\partial z}} + {F_x} &= 0` for the first equation eliminates indeed the undesired space of my question than increases the space in the `cases` environment between the last symbol of each equation and the symbol of equality.

Comment: Other than that, you also can do it using `empheq`and the `alignat*` environment.